# Encountering 404 Errors when attempting to get vim package (Ubuntu 22 / Jammy )

Tags: package-management, 22.04, vim

I'm still a pretty big noob when it comes to everything unix / command line related however I am attempting to download Vim via command line and I keep getting the following errors:

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Only other posts I've found encountering similar issues are due to outdated OS or using a proxy, both of which are not applicable in my case, however I am inclined to believe it is a network issue. Just not sure how to even start

Comment: Run `sudo apt update`.  Your repository information is outdated, and you always should run `sudo apt update` before running any package install commands to make sure you have the latest information on available packages.

Comment: Do: `apt-cache search vim`. It will provide a list of all installable `vim*` packages.

Comment: Your apt sources are a mess, which is why you have so many apt errors. See [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)